# Trying to reset the auto increment value of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

First off, I've gone through the normal steps to try and reset a value, GUI and CLI, it says x rows affected.

I have all the permissions I would need to do this(any amazon specific ones i don't know about aside), locally the queries work fine.

Is there a way to modify my tables auto increment number so that it starts at say 19, and not 1,000,021?

Queries I've tried.

```
ALTER TABLE X AUTO_INCREMENT = 19
```

I have all permissions granted to all tables, and I have even tried granting ALTER specifically to my user on the specific db.table.

Any insight or a push in the right direction would be lovely.

Answer (score 0):

Your command:

```
ALTER TABLE X AUTO_INCREMENT = 19
```

will work only if your table does NOT have row with id 19 present. If you try to insert new row which would cause insertion conflict, it will automatically reset to maximum existing value of your auto-increment column + 1. In other words, if you have rows with id 19 and 1000020 (maximum), it will automatically reset to 1000021 on any attempt to insert.

Comment: To elaborate a little further, I made sentinel values in the table and am now unable to reset back to where i was before adding them, in this case, 19.